# Sending alert to user when he is near to a specific location

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2, android-geofence

I'm developing an app that must send a notification to users when they are in range of 200m of a specific location.

My users are car drivers. When I used Google Geofencing API and tested it while I was driving, there was a big delay sometimes as it was sending me the notification after I passed the range.

I thought about adding a location tracker every 3 seconds and calculate the distance from user current location to the wanted location and if the distance is less than 200m I would send a notification.

Anyone knows any other solution or an API that might handle it?

Here is the `GeoFencing` Code

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        ResultCallback<Status>{   
    @BindView(R.id.tvLocation)
    MatabTextView tvLocation;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    WaveFormView waveFormView;
    protected ArrayList<Geofence> mGeofenceList;
    protected GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        waveFormView = (WaveFormView) findViewById(R.id.Wave);
        waveFormView.updateAmplitude(0.05f, true);
        waveFormView.updateAmplitude(0.1f, true);
        waveFormView.updateAmplitude(0.2f, true);
        waveFormView.updateAmplitude(0.5f, true);
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy old = StrictMode.getThreadPolicy();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder(old)
                .permitDiskWrites()
                .build());

        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(old);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        mGeofenceList = new ArrayList<Geofence>();
        populateGeofenceList();
        buildGoogleApiClient();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting() || !mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }

    public void addGeofencesButtonHandler(View view) {
        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Google API Client not connected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        try {
            LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofences(
                    mGoogleApiClient,
                    getGeofencingRequest(),
                    getGeofencePendingIntent()
            ).setResultCallback(this); // Result processed in onResult().
        } catch (SecurityException securityException) {
            // Catch exception generated if the app does not use ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission.
        }

    }

    private GeofencingRequest getGeofencingRequest() {
        GeofencingRequest.Builder builder = new GeofencingRequest.Builder();
        builder.setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER | GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_EXIT);
        builder.addGeofences(mGeofenceList);
        return builder.build();
    }

    private PendingIntent getGeofencePendingIntent() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, GeofenceTransitionsIntentService.class);
        // We use FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT so that we get the same pending intent back when calling addgeoFences()
        return PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    }

    public void onResult(Status status) {
        if (status.isSuccess()) {
            Toast.makeText(
                    this,
                    "Geofences Added",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show();
        } else {
                  String errorMessage = GeofenceErrorMessages.getErrorString(this,
                  status.getStatusCode());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting() || mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        // Do something with result.getErrorCode());
        Log.d("Geofencing", String.valueOf(result.getErrorCode()));
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }

    public void populateGeofenceList() {

        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("roads").child("Name").child("locations");
        myRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mGeofenceList.add(new Geofence.Builder()
                        .setRequestId(dataSnapshot.getKey())
                        .setCircularRegion(
                                (Double) dataSnapshot.child("lat").getValue(),
                                (Double) dataSnapshot.child("lang").getValue(),
                                Constants.GEOFENCE_RADIUS_IN_METERS
                        )
                        .setExpirationDuration(Geofence.NEVER_EXPIRE)
                        .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER
                        )
                        .build());
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        for (Map.Entry<String, LatLng> entry : Constants.LANDMARKS.entrySet()) {

        }
    }

}
```

And the `GeofenceTransitionsIntentService` service.

```
public class GeofenceTransitionsIntentService extends IntentService {
    protected static final String TAG = "GeofenceTransitionsIS";

    public GeofenceTransitionsIntentService() {
        super(TAG);  // use TAG to name the IntentService worker thread
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        GeofencingEvent event = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);
        String description = getGeofenceTransitionDetails(event);
        sendNotification(description);
        if (event.hasError()) {
            Log.e(TAG, "GeofencingEvent Error: " + event.getErrorCode());
            return;
        }
    }

    private static String getGeofenceTransitionDetails(GeofencingEvent event) {
        String transitionString =
                GeofenceStatusCodes.getStatusCodeString(event.getGeofenceTransition());
        List triggeringIDs = new ArrayList();
        for (Geofence geofence : event.getTriggeringGeofences()) {
            triggeringIDs.add(geofence.getRequestId());
        }
        return String.format("%s: %s", transitionString, TextUtils.join(", ", triggeringIDs));
    }

    private void sendNotification(String notificationDetails) {
        // Create an explicit content Intent that starts MainActivity.
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MapsActivity.class);

        // Get a PendingIntent containing the entire back stack.
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(MapsActivity.class).addNextIntent(notificationIntent);
        PendingIntent notificationPendingIntent =
                stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        // Get a notification builder that's compatible with platform versions >= 4
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        // Define the notification settings.
        builder.setColor(Color.RED)
                .setContentTitle(notificationDetails)
                .setSound(alarmSound)
                .setContentText("Click notification to return to App")
                .setContentIntent(notificationPendingIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setAutoCancel(true);

        // Fire and notify the built Notification.
        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
    }
}
```

Comment: Try Firebase database for real time callback and generating notification in your application on demand.

Comment: Have u read the [troubleshoot](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html#Troubleshooting) part in android docs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, unless you are willing to pay a fee to Google for using their API, i strongly recommend you to develop using the OSMDroid library instead.

If you want linear distance (radius) and not polygon location detection, geofencing is overkill which will cost you dearly in battery use and device temperature.

Determining the linear distance from your target's position to the desired location is easy.  You may use this code, for example:

```
public double distanceGeoPoints (GeoPoint geoPoint01, GeoPoint geoPoint02) {
    double lat1 = geoPoint01.getLatitudeE6()/1E6;
    double lng1 = geoPoint01.getLongitudeE6()/1E6;
    double lat2 = geoPoint02.getLatitudeE6()/1E6;
    double lng2 = geoPoint02.getLongitudeE6()/1E6;
    double earthRadius = 3958.75;
    double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2-lat1);
    double dLng = Math.toRadians(lng2-lng1);
    double a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
               Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) *
               Math.sin(dLng/2) * Math.sin(dLng/2);
    double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
    double dist = earthRadius * c;

    int meterConversion = 1609;
    double geopointDistance = dist * meterConversion;

    return geopointDistance;
}
```

This is the Haversine Formula, generally accepted as "precise enough for most intents and purposes".  You must understand that the Earth is not a perfect sphere, it is more like a baseball after Big Pappy uses it repeatedly for batting practice.

From what i see from your app, this should give you the necessary precision.  But do [read more](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographical_distance) if you are curious.

Comment: This really is a prefect answer,on asking the question i was implementing getting a distance between 2 locations using method 
Location1.distanceTo(location2);
it worked fine but i want to know which is better in getting a precise distance( radius)? what i have just done or your recommended method?

Comment: i dont know how the API calculates distances between geopoints, but i would guess that Google's API will give you at least the same precision, if not more.   But i can not stress enough how much i recommend NOT using Google's mapping API without discussing costs with client.  They are very strict in enforcing charges on professional apps.  What you are doing competes directly with their cashcow: advertising (they sell ads to businesses to attract passersby as local potential customers).

Comment: Great thanks alot for your answer i will try your method and see the results and will try to give up on Google maps

Comment: if you need anything re OSMDroid, dont be shy.  i have tons of code which i can make available.   I write tracking apps, mobile integrated with webbased (i use OSM on both - yes GoogleAPI's are easier, but they are proprietary and code gets deprecated, which means you might have to maintain your software for years to come)

Comment: when using OSM, if you want to geocode and reverse geocode (get address from coordinates and viceversa) do consider Nominatim.  Ive been using it for years.  You can even download and cache the complete db (which they recommend BTW), many many Gigs, though.